# @ConfigurationProperties and @EnableConfigurationProperties cannot bind any properties in .yml or .properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to new a project like mybatis-spring-boot-starter, I use springboot 2.3.2, but something wrong.
First of all, I define a BatisProperties.java like following:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = BatisProperties.MYBATIS_PREFIX)
    public class BatisProperties {
    public static final String MYBATIS_PREFIX = "batis";
    private String MyClassName;
    ...
}
```

then, a BatisAutoConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({ SqlSessionFactory.class, SqlSessionFactoryBean.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties(BatisProperties.class)
public class BatisAutoConfiguration implements InitializingBean {
    private final BatisProperties properties;
@Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        checkConfigFileExists();
    }

    private void checkConfigFileExists() {
        System.out.println(this.properties.getMyClassName());//null here
        if (this.properties.isCheckConfigLocation() && //code from mybatis-spring-booot-starter
        StringUtils.hasText(this.properties.getConfigLocation())) {
            Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource(this.properties.getConfigLocation());
            Assert.state(resource.exists(),
                    "Cannot find config location: " + resource + " (please add config file or check your Mybatis configuration)");
        }
    }
```

And in /resource/META_INF/spring.factories

```
# Auto Configure
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
xxx.BatisAutoConfiguration
```

above are all in a starter, I compile it to a jar file and use this jar file in another project(project TWO), in project TWO, I define .properties or .yml in /resource directory, contents are:

```
batis.my-class-name=xxxx.xxxx
```

Finally, a DemoApplication.java or Test.java like following:

DemoApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    private BatisProperties properties;

    private static BatisProperties batisProperties;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        batisProperties = properties;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println(batisProperties.toString());//xxxx.BatisProperties@436390f4
        System.out.println(batisProperties.getMyClassName());//null

    }
}
```

Test.java

```
@SpringBootTest
class Test {
 
    @Autowired
    private BatisProperties properties;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println(properties);// some bean in Spring IOC
        System.out.println(properties.getDatasourceConfigProviderClassName());// null       
    }
}
```

Above comments are the results: We can find BatisProperties Bean in Spring IOC, but all properties are null.

So anybody can help? I don't know whether it is caused by the version of SpringBoot

Comment: Rather than sharing isolated piece of code in text, it would be way more effective to move that in a sample repo on your GitHub account. That way we could run that test ourselves and be able to help you quickly. Can you please do that?

Comment: That too but you could also add the yml that is supposed to be loaded in the @ConfigurationProperties

Answer (score 0):

I would improve the BatisProperties class to be as:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "batis")
public class BatisProperties {
    private String MyClassName;
    ... 
    // Make sure you have getters and setter for properties!
    // If you use Lombok, put @Data on this class.
    ...
}
```

There is no need to explicitly have BatisAutoConfiguration.java. Just let Spring initialize it for you. Completely remove the class BatisAutoConfiguration.java. Also do not use static fields for the property class.

Try the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);    
    }
}
```

Or also more explicit, but **not** needed:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.app.org"}) // prefix, where BatisProperties is
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);    
    }
}
```

or:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import(BatisProperties.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);    
    }
}
```

The BatisProperties should be available anywhere in your App.